# s3cmd - delete first file if total number files more than 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wish to create a daily cronjob, using s3cmd, to check if a S3 bucket has more than 5 backup files. If more than 5 then delete the oldest one leaving 5; and if less than 5 there will be no file deletion.

Therefore, the s3 bucket will always leave 5 backup copies.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use S3 lifecycle rules for your use case. This will avoid your effort in writing a cron that runs daily.

[S3 Object Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)

If you want you use Cron in a scenario where you don't backup daily then in that case use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and in that use

> aws s3 ls

in combination with your logic and

> aws s3 delete

command to achieve the same.